# Handle click event in the modalBottomsheet content in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I Have a ModalBottomSheet and I want to change a boolean value after clicking on the bottom sheet transparent background. How can I access this view click listener?

I don't want to use BottomSheetScaffold.

```
fun ScheduleJobFromQueuedBottomSheet(
    viewModel: ProductViewModel,
    onClickCancel: () -> Unit,
    onQueuedScheduleRequestResultIsBack: () -> Unit,
) {
**var state by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }**

val bottomSheetState: ModalBottomSheetState =
        rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded, confirmStateChange = {
            it != ModalBottomSheetValue.HalfExpanded
        }, animationSpec = TweenSpec(durationMillis = 300, delay = 10))


    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = bottomSheetState,
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = custom, topEnd = custom),
        scrimColor = ModalBottomSheetDefaults.scrimColor.copy(alpha = 0.40f),
        sheetContent = {
            ReviewBookingScheduledBottomSheet(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight(),
                viewModel = viewModel,
                onClickCancel = {
                    onClickCancel.invoke()
                }, onScheduledRequestResultIsBack = {
                    onQueuedScheduleRequestResultIsBack.invoke()
                })
        }
    ) {

    }
}
```

I want to change the state value by clicking on the bottom sheet background (Not bottomsheet content)

Comment: show your code.

Comment: Are you want change boolean value after bottom sheet dismiss?

Comment: Yes. but I don't want to check  if(bottomSheetState.HIDDEN){  state = true}

Answer (score 2):

In Compose observability is preferred over callbacks, thus there isn't an explicit listener available.

We can observe the transparent background click by observing the `bottomSheetState` state change when hidden:

```
fun ScheduleJobFromQueuedBottomSheet(
    viewModel: ProductViewModel,
    onClickCancel: () -> Unit,
    onQueuedScheduleRequestResultIsBack: () -> Unit,
) {
var state by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

val bottomSheetState: ModalBottomSheetState =
        rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded, confirmStateChange = {
            it != ModalBottomSheetValue.HalfExpanded
        }, animationSpec = TweenSpec(durationMillis = 300, delay = 10))

LaunchedEffect(bottomSheetState) {
    snapshotFlow { bottomSheetState.currentValue }
        .filter { it == Hidden }
        .collect { state = true }
}


    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = bottomSheetState,
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = custom, topEnd = custom),
        scrimColor = ModalBottomSheetDefaults.scrimColor.copy(alpha = 0.40f),
        sheetContent = {
            ReviewBookingScheduledBottomSheet(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight(),
                viewModel = viewModel,
                onClickCancel = {
                    onClickCancel.invoke()
                }, onScheduledRequestResultIsBack = {
                    onQueuedScheduleRequestResultIsBack.invoke()
                })
        }
    ) {

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this can't differentiate if the `bottomSheetState` change is due to click on the transparent background or due to other change by the state. If you have a use case that requires observing *only* for transparent background click but not other dismiss action, please leave a comment here: https://buganizer.corp.google.com/issues/256755735

Answer (score 1):

Add one boolean mutableState variable and change this value when your bottom sheet state change

```
  var isBottomSheetDismissed = remember { mutableStateOf(false) } 

val bottomSheetState: ModalBottomSheetState =
    rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded, confirmStateChange = {

        isBottomSheetDismissed.value = it==ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden
        it != ModalBottomSheetValue.HalfExpanded
      
    }, animationSpec = TweenSpec(durationMillis = 300, delay = 10))
```

Comment: If you want this boolean outside of this method, it's called "state hoisting" - refer this official document https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state

Comment: it's not working correctly, the isBottomSheetDismissed value is a state in the view model. when I changed it in the remember my state is recomposed and blinking

Comment: Yes. If you change the state variable it will recompose the function. 

Try with livedata instead of state variable @jasonR